# replacing value in an object if null in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

how do we replace each key value if its null in a foreach ? every key value in an object if its null replace it with '-' ..

I have a sample basic example below , thanks.

#my sample code

```
res.items.forEach(v => {
              if(v === null) {
                v[v] = '-';
              }
              if(v.proposedTerm) {
                v.proposedTerm = Math.round(v.proposedTerm * 10) / 10 +  ' ' + 'years';
              }....
```

#sample object

```
[
    {
        "id": 499,
        "name": "118-A",
        "annualRentProposed": "$343,433",
        "annualRentCurrent": "$353,120.04",
        "firmTermRemainingCurrent": "10.8 years",
        "maxAvailableTerm": "10.6 years",
        "cashContribution": "$121,111",
        "cashFlow": "$543,834.54",
        "description": "adasdas",
        "wagAnnualCurrent": 353120.04,
        "wagFirmTermRemainingCurrent": 10.75,
        "partnerTermStart": null,
        "partnerTermEnd": null,
        "partnerCam": null,
        "partnerServiceFreeAndSecurityMonitoring": null,
        "proposedTerm": "23.2 years",
        "proposedMaxAvailableTerm": null,
        "partner": null,
        "partnerBaseRent": null,
        "createdOnString": "10/12/2021",
        "fileName": null,
        "serverFileName": null,
        "size": null,
        "absoluteUri": null,
        "sentTo": null
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you show what res.items looks like. Also which property you are expecting be null and replacing

Comment: its an array of objects https://imgur.com/a/8IXjSHM

Comment: if property is null replace it with "-"

Comment: Please add your image here directly. It helps everyone

Comment: i added sample object above , please check

Comment: What exactly do you do with this array? Are you just displaying it somewhere? You probably should be using `map()` instead of `forEach()`. You could probably just use `??` at the part of the code you're reading the items. It all depends on what you're doing for the best approach.

Comment: No , I need some of the values https://imgur.com/a/FHCMjIJ , but if the value of property is null replace it with '-'

Comment: Ok but do you display this anywhere? The code looks like it's meant for displaying these values somewhere... whatever you're doing would probably be best served with a pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over the items array first and then iterate over each key of the object. You need nested `forEach` for this.

res.items can have multiple elements so run a `forEach()`.
Now each of this element is an object with properties, so use `Object.keys()` to get the properties in an array. Check the value and replace

```
res.items.forEach(item => {
        Object.keys(item).forEach(x => {
              if(item[x] === null) {
                item[x] = '-';
              }
    ......
   }
}
```